# Sleeping near San Jose airport (Costa Rica)

Tags: budget, hotels, costa-rica, sjo, san-jose

I am arriving at the San Jose airport in Costa Rica rather late in the evening (with small children). I would like to stay overnight somewhere close, ideally without going into San Jose itself (which I don't really want to visit anyway) and even better arrange for someone from the hotel to pick us up. What are my options on low to mid budget?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Hotel Mi Tierra (2nd Ave., Alajuela)](http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g309224-d967186-Reviews-Hotel_Mi_Tierra-Alajuela_Province_of_Alajuela.html) is family friendly and has some good reviews, and it's [about 2.5 km north of the Airport](http://goo.gl/maps/6sDbd).

Answer (score 3):

I can recommend [Maleku Hostel](http://www.malekuhostel.com/) in Alajuela  ([Hostelworld entry](http://www.hostelworld.com/hosteldetails.php/Maleku-Hostel/Alajuela/19744)). It's comfy, and located a [short drive](http://goo.gl/maps/pGDjm) (2 km or 5 min) away from the airport. Also, they offer:

> Free shuttle to the airport (from Hostel TO Airport, starting 5am to
>   5pm)

...so it's a great place to stay before a morning flight out of SJO.

There are [private rooms](http://www.malekuhostel.com/RatesandFacilities.htm) available (from USD 25), so I think it's good for families too. (I stayed in a dorm and paid $12 (March 2011), but looks like it's $15 now.)

---

As for other low budget options, there's also [Alajuela Backpackers](http://alajuelabackpackers.com/), with [slightly mixed reviews](http://www.hostelworld.com/hosteldetails.php/Alajuela-Backpackers/Alajuela/36409/reviews).